# Using custom marker

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I would like to use a custom marker (image) to my map.

Currently my code looks like this:

```
<script>
function myMap() {
  var mapCanvas = document.getElementById("map");
  var mapOptions = {
    center: new google.maps.LatLng(47.3921611, 8.4957963),
    zoom: 14
  }

  var map = new google.maps.Map(mapCanvas, mapOptions);
}
</script>
```

How can I implement it to my code?

Comment: There aren't any markers in the posted code.

Comment: @geocodezip if there was a marker, there wouldn't be a question.

Comment: https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/icon-simple

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From [Google's "simple Marker" example](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/icon-simple):

```
var image = 'https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/full/images/beachflag.png';
    var beachMarker = new google.maps.Marker({
      position: {lat: -33.890, lng: 151.274},
      map: map,
      icon: image
    });
```

Code snippet with it added to the code in your question:

```js
function myMap() {
  var mapCanvas = document.getElementById("map");
  var mapOptions = {
    center: new google.maps.LatLng(47.3921611, 8.4957963),
    zoom: 14
  }

  var map = new google.maps.Map(mapCanvas, mapOptions);
  var image = 'https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/full/images/beachflag.png';
  var beachMarker = new google.maps.Marker({
    position: map.getCenter(),
    map: map,
    icon: image
  });
}
google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', myMap);
```

```css
html,
body,
#map {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js"></script>
<div id="map"></div>
```

Comment: That's just what I wanted. Thank you so much!